# IBM APIConnect - customize email "Application plan subscription approval request."

Tags: apiconnect

Using IBM APIConnect. When an user subcribe to a product that requires an approvation on the developer portal, an email is sent with the subject

"**Application plan subscription approval request.**"

and text

"User %username%(%email%) requests subscription to plan "%plan%" for application "%application%".
You can approve / deny the subscription request, using the following link: ..."

I would like to change this template to add the Product name. Where can I customize this email template? Can I customize it from the developer portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to customize the message.